# Merge two objects without overwriting same properties

Tags: javascript

Given the following 2 objects in Javascript:

```js
let sample1 = {a: 1}
let sample2 = {a: 1000, b: 2000, c: 3000}
```

How can I merge them into one without overwriting the properties from the first object?
I tried both `Object.assign` and the spread operator `...` but both of them are are overwriting my properties, so what is the best solution without using lodash?

The desired output would be:

```js
const result = {a: 1, b: 2000, c: 3000}
```

Comment: `Object.assign({}, sample2, sample1)`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @Taplar - I guess that seems like what the OP wants, but it  would overwrite properties when `sample2` contains the keys that `sample1` does. I don't think having multiple keys in the same object is possible because objects can't have duplicate keys, at least not at the same hierarchy--how would you access them otherwise?

Comment: @marsnebulasoup The last line of the question in their `const result` line shows they want that.  The result has the non-duplicate properties from sample2, and the value from sample1 for a that is a dupe.

Comment: @Taplar - okay I don't think I understood the question then, because I thought that `const result...` was what they didn't want for some reason

Comment: just use object destructuring in order
const result = { ...sample2, ...sample1}

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want. It says in the title that you don't want to overwrite properties but you state your desired result ('so what is solution withou lodash const result = {a: 1, b: 2000, c: 3000}') would be to overwrite `sample2.a`. Anyway you can't have two ID's with the same name merge together unless you change one of the ID names (to my knowledge. If you did then your resulting object would be more like an array, I think). In any event you can do this, but I'm not sure what you want.. can you clarify your problem? I hope I understood your problem correctly (I am new to Stackoverflow).

```js
var sample1 = {a: 1};
var sample2 = {a: 1000, b: 2000, c: 3000};
var collection = {sample1, sample2};
console.log("the merged samples: ");
console.log(collection);
console.log("how to access collection.sample1: ");
console.log(collection.sample1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to merge your two objects without affecting the keys already in the first object, you could create your own utilitary function like this.

```
function mergeObjectWithoutOverwriting(mainObject, objectToMerge) {
  Object.keys(objectToMerge).forEach(key => {
    if (!mainObject[key]) mainObject[key] = objectToMerge[key]
  })
  return mainObject
}
```

Then use it to merge your objects.

```
var sample1 = {a: 1};
var sample2 = {a: 1000, b: 2000, c: 3000};

var mergedSample = mergeObjectWithoutOverwriting(sample1, sample2)
```

The result will be {a: 1, b: 2000, c: 3000}

Answer (score -1):

```
let obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
let obj2 = { a: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

// Expected output: obj1 = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}}

for (let key in obj2) {      
  if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {       
    obj1[key] = obj2[key];      
  }
}
```